# Re-arranging the equation $t=\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\tan\theta\right)$ to find $\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I re-array the equation

> $t=\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\tan \theta\right)$

to find the equation of $\theta$.

> $\theta=\,?$

Actually I tried this equation:

> $\theta=\frac{\arctan\left(\tan t\right)}{\frac {a}{b}}$

but it didn't work.

Comment: hint - apply $tg$ to both sides. and please don't write in capitals, doesn't really encourage people to provide answers you'd like

Comment: 1. Don't shout at us. 2. Show some effort. 3. Don't think we give you a full homework solution.

Comment: This seems obvious to me. May I ask what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ali I tried $\theta=\frac{\arctan\left(tan t\right)}{\frac {a}{b}}$

Comment: I can probably make this a solution, but I'm not sure it's worth it. This is how it's done: 1. Applying $\tan$ to both sides of the equation $\tan(t)=\tan \left(\arctan{ \left(\frac{a}{b} \tan{\theta}\right)} \right)=\frac{a}{b} \tan \theta$ 2. Rearranging the equation: $\tan \theta = \frac{b}{a} \tan{t}$ 3. Getting $\arctan$ from both sides: $\theta=\arctan{\left( \frac{b}{a}\tan{t}\right) }$

Comment: @mm-aops I don't think writing in capitals annoying people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{array}{rl}
t
=
\arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\,\tan\,\theta\right)
\implies 
&
\tan (t) =\tan\left( \arctan\left(\frac{a}{b}\,\tan\,\theta\right)\right)
\\
\implies
&
\tan (t) =\frac{a}{b}\,\tan\,\theta
\\
\implies
&
\frac{b}{a}\tan (t) =\,\tan\,\theta
\\
\implies
&
\tan\,\theta = \frac{b}{a}\tan (t)
\\
\implies
&
\arctan\left(\tan\,\theta\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\tan (t)\right)
\\
\implies
&
\arctan\left(\tan\,\theta\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\tan (t)\right)
\\
\implies
&
\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\tan (t)\right)+k\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb Z
\\
\end{array}